# How to show a property from an object inside an array in Vue data during a loop defined on the Template?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vuejs2, properties

My data structure:

```
data: {
    OBJs: [ 
        { "imageUrl": "site/image1.png", "name": "name1" }, 
        { "imageUrl": "site/image2.png", "name": "name2" }, 
        { "imageUrl": "site/image3.png", "name": "name3" }, 
        { "imageUrl": "site/image4.png", "name": "name4" }, 
        ]
}
```

Then on the template

```
<div v-for="index in OBJs.length" :key="index">
    {{OBJs[index].imageUrl}}
</div>
```

But I keep getting this error.

[image]

If I render just the OBJs[index] like this:

```
<div v-for="index in OBJs.length" :key="index">
    {{OBJs[index]}}
</div>
```

...I get the all objects!

```
 { "imageUrl": "site/image1.png", "name": "name1" }
 { "imageUrl": "site/image2.png", "name": "name2" } 
 { "imageUrl": "site/image3.png", "name": "name3" } 
 { "imageUrl": "site/image4.png", "name": "name4" }
```

so how come are they undefined? Anybody able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to use `length`

just `OBJs` - then you will have item of array on each iteration

if you have structure like this:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            data: {
                OBJs: [ 
                    { "imageUrl": "site/image1.png", "name": "name1" }, 
                    { "imageUrl": "site/image2.png", "name": "name2" }, 
                    { "imageUrl": "site/image3.png", "name": "name3" }, 
                    { "imageUrl": "site/image4.png", "name": "name4" }, 
                    ]
            }
        };
    }
};
```

UI:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in data.OBJs" :key="item">{{item.imageUrl}}</li>
</ul>
```